# General expression for coefficients of power expansion to a power $\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty (ax)^j\right)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, factorial

I am working with a set of equations where I need to expand the sum of a geometric series to a power, something of the form:
\begin{equation}
\left[1+(ax)+(ax)^2+(ax)^3+\ldots\right]^n \quad \mbox{or} \quad \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty (ax)^j\right)^n \quad \mbox{where} \quad |ax|<1
\end{equation}
This operation is necessary as I need to equate the resulting coefficients of powers of $x$. I have straightforwardly determined that the $i$^th coefficient, $C_i$, of the expansion is given by:

for $n=1$:

\begin{equation}
1+(ax)+(ax)^2+(ax)^3+\ldots \quad \mbox{so} \quad C_i = 1
\end{equation}

for $n=2$:

\begin{equation}
1+2(ax)+3(ax)^2+4(ax)^3+\ldots \quad \mbox{so} \quad C_i = i
\end{equation}

for $n=3$

\begin{equation}
1+3(ax)+6(ax)^2+10(ax)^3+\ldots\quad \mbox{so} \quad C_i = i\frac{\left(i+1\right)}{2}
\end{equation}

and for $n=4$:

\begin{equation}
1+4(ax)+10(ax)^2+15(ax)^3+\ldots \quad \mbox{so} \quad C_i = i\frac{\left(i+1\right)}{2}\frac{\left(i+2\right)}{3}
\end{equation}

and so on... Is there a general way to write this as a series in the form:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^\infty f\left(C_i\right) (ax)^{i-1}
\end{equation}

I can see that this requires some form of factorial expression, but my factorial manipulation is very rusty. Any assistance gratefully received.

Comment: an infinite number - I perhaps should have written: $\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty (ax)^j\right)^n$, and have now amended the post to reflect that

Comment: Yes it is - but I have already converted this from $1/(1-ax)^n$

Comment: So why not expand that using the binomial theorem?

Comment: Ah - you mean, as in this post, for example:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624974/series-expansion-1-1-xn

Comment: Yes that’s the idea

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series?wprov=sfla1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $n$-th power of a geometric series is a *[binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*. We can perform a binomial series expansion and obtain

> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\left(ax\right)^j\right)^n}&=\left(\frac{1}{1-ax}\right)^n\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{(1-ax)^n}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{-n}{j}(-ax)^j\tag{2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+j-1}{j}(ax)^j}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

We see the wanted coefficient $f(C_{i+1})=\binom{n+j-1}{j}=\frac{(n+j-1)!}{j!(n-1)!}$.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the *[geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum)* expansion.
- In (2) we use the *[binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* expansion.
- In (3) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a general form for

$$C_{i,{n+1}}=\frac{i(i+1)(i+2)\cdots (i+n-1)}{n!}$$ as you've defined it, with $C_{i,1}=1.$ This is given by

$$C_{i,{n+1}}=\frac{(i+n-1)!}{n!(i-1)!}$$ because the factorial descends from $i+n-1$, but needs a product underneath to cancel the other terms past $i$ in the numerator such as $i-1$ and so on.